# Why does the name of ハチ公 【こう】 include Katakana instead of Hiragana?

Tags: katakana, orthography, names, furigana

It seems strange because the name ハチ公 【こう】 combines Katakana and Kanji in one word.

Comment: Related http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15199/1628

Comment: Note that Japanese people were using Katakana instead of Hiragana in pre-WWII.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The nickname ハチ公 consists of the name ハチ followed by the suffix 〜公.

*Katakana* is a common choice for writing names, even if the actual name is written with *kanji*.

The suffix 〜公 is described in 大辞林 as follows

> **こう**【公】
>
> ［一］（名）  [...]
>
> ［二］（代）  [...]
>
> ［三］（接尾）
> ①身分の高い人の名に付けて、敬意を表す。「家康━」
> ②人や動物の名前に付けて、親しみ、あるいはやや軽んずる気持ちを表す。「忠犬ハチ━」「熊━」

The suffix 〜公 is added to the names of people (of high standing) to show respect or (by extension) to names of people or animals to express affection/intimacy.

Comment: I have seen Katakana for foreign names; but I was not aware it could be used for native names as well. When do we see it used for native names?

Comment: @solidsnack I think pet names are *usually* in katakana (タマ for cats, ポチ for dogs, ...) while some prefer hiragana/kanji names. Katakana for human nicknames are also very common.